# What is the percent of players in the top X that are women for different values of X?

Tags: statistics, women

I have already found some numbers thanks to this website: http://www.ferimex.com/icc/frl.php?list=0&country=0&title=0&sex=0&year=0&old=0&cat=0&size=9&update=yes

- Top 50: 0 = 0%
- Top 100: 2 = 2%
- Top 200: 2 = 1%
- Top 300: 3 = 1%
- Top 400: 4 = 1%
- Top 500: 6 = 1.2%
- Top 600: 12 = 2%
- Top 700: 15 = 2.14%
- Top 800: 16 = 2%
- Top 900: 19 = 2.11%
- Top 1000: 29 = 2.9%
- Top 1100: 33 = 3%
- Top 1200: 36 = 3%
- Top 1300: 43 = 3.31%
- Top 1400: 45 = 3.21%
- Top 1500: 45 = 3%
- Top 1600: 49 = 3.06%
- Top 1700: 54 = 3.18%
- Top 1800: 57 = 3.17%
- Top 1900: 61 = 3.21%
- Top 2000: 65 = 3.25%

And I plotted the graph:

[image]

It's clearly increasing.

But I couldn't go higher than top 2000. I hope that someone will be able to extend the graph for higher values (for higher values the graph should be smoother because there will be less statistical fluctuations).

Comment: it's not necessarily linear. I would expect it to be logistic. I wonder how well your points would fit to that.

Answer (score 8):

What I would suggest you do which will allow you to get these statistics for yourself is to go to the [FIDE ratings advanced search](https://ratings.fide.com/advseek.phtml) page. There you can choose options like:

rating 2400 - 3000

sex: both

exclude inactive: tick

and you will get the answer "2184" followed by a list of players and their details. Repeat this with "sex: female" and you will get 66 followed by the list.

Repeat this for 2300 and you get total: 5073, female: 185, so percentage is 3.65%.

For 2000 you get 1473 / 31866 = 4.62%

For 1500 you get 7167 / 100730 = 7.12% and so on.

This way you can go as far as you want and in whatever detail you want.

Answer (score 4):

Like @Brian Towers, I suggest using FIDE data. However, I suggest you to download instead the [full rating lists](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) and analyse them using some kind of statistical software (like R).

According to the FIDE rating list of September 2015 there are 128196 active players, 12320 of which are women, almost 10%. As you can see in the graph below, the proportion of women players increases in the lower categories. And it decreases dramatically near the elite.

[image: Percentage of women in the top X players]